# Awk - Multiline matching, printing filename and match

Tags: awk

I have the following awk command:

```
awk -v RS=! -v ORS= '/abc/ && /def/ {print FILENAME;}' files
```

This looks in each file in files, separates each record in the file by a '!', and then matches the record to 'abc' and 'def'. The above code will then print the name of the file. If I remove the `{print FILENAME}` it will print the whole record if matched.

A file would look like:

```
abc1
bce
bcd
def
!
abc2
bce
def
!
```

I want to print out the filename and the line that matches 'abc'. For example:

```
file1
abc1

file2
abc2
abc3
```

How can I go about this?

Comment: Do you want filenames printed out if no files match? Do you need this done in the context of your example awk script (modification to that script)? Or is something like @nu11p01n73R's answer acceptable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
awk 'FNR==1{print FILENAME} /abc/' file1 file2
```

The `FNR` field is set to `1` a new file is read. `FNR==1` is true, at the first line of each input file, where the action to be performed is `print FILENAME` which will print `file1` and `file2`

`/abc/`  will match all lines containing `abc` since no action is specified, default being print the entire record (`$0`) is performed. Which is similar as writing `/abc/{print $0}`

```
file1
abc1

file2
abc2
abc3
```

Answer (score 4):

```
awk 'FNR==1{fname=FILENAME"\n"} /abc/{printf "%s%s\n", (fname?fname:""), $0; fname=""}' files
```